# "a.exe ( source code file - a.cpp) has stopped working."

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array

So , using codeblocks , i have just written a small cpp program. But it unexpectly shows this error (see image). Can't figure out what's wrong.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mat[1000][1000];
    cout<<"done";
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're probably out of stack.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` no, stop.

Comment: I will be needing 2d array of that size. Anything that could be done ?

Comment: Yes, use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: Runs fine: https://ideone.com/mSo7O4 Try running it inside your IDE so you can get a more meaningful error message.

Comment: @O.O.Balance Stack space differs from machine to machine, this says nothing.

Comment: [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: @SombreroChicken Absolutely. So does "a.exe has stopped working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int mat[1000][1000];` is creating a huge array on the stack. Probably more than your compiler/platform allows.

You have several options:

1) tell your compiler to use more space for the stack.

2) allocate your objects on the heap.

3) just stop using C arrays and use a `std::vector` instead.